# nmap in bash script returns error

Tags: linux, bash, script, nmap

I want to find out all my available routers with `nmap`.

Typing this in command line returns the expected output.

```
nmap --script=broadcast-dchp-discover -e eno1
```

---

But when I try to run this command in a short bash script `nmap` returns an error:

```
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:801: 'broadcast-dchp-discover' did not match a category, filename, or directory
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:801: in function 'get_chosen_scripts'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1251: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the commandline options:

wrong: broadcast-dchp-discover
correct: broadcast-dhcp-discover